# How to pass shell variable to dependent/downstream job in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have 2 jenkins jobs, J1 and J2. J2 is triggered once J1 is completed successfully. J2 also has a quiet period of 't' seconds. I generate some variables in a shell build step in J1 and I want to pass these to J2.

I tried using Jenkins parameterised trigger plugin but wasn't able to pass shell variables.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If J2 is (or can be) a parameterized build job, then I have done this using a "trigger/call builds on other projects" step or a "conditional step" containing a "trigger/call builds on other projects" sub-step.

The Conditional Step allows you to control when J2 is kicked. The Trigger/Call builds step or sub-step will allow you to pass parameters from one build to another in a variety of ways including parameters with variables from the current job substituted.

Conditional Steps are provided by the [Conditional BuildStep Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin), the parameterized builds are provided by the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin).